# Rails Haml - join hash values by index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

```
- @nutritions = Hash.new
    - @ingredients.each_with_index do |ingredient,i|
      - ingredient.nutritions.each_with_index do |nutrition, j|
        - @nutritions[[i,j]] = nutrition.amount
    - @nutritions.each do |nutrition|
      = nutrition
```

gives me two "blocks" with amounts (example has 2 ingredients, with 4 nutritions):

```
[[ingredient, nutrition], amount]

[[0, 0], 900.0]
[[0, 1], 3769.0]
[[0, 2], 0.0]
[[0, 3], 100.0] 

[[1, 0], 258.0]
[[1, 1], 1080.0]
[[1, 2], 64.0]
[[1, 3], 0.0]
```

I'm searching for a way to add up each hash value (amount),
and store it in another key behind, like

```
[[2, 0], 1158.0]
[[2, 1], 4849.0]
[[2, 2], 64.0]
[[2, 3], 100.0]
```

So. If there're 5 ingredients, store the sum of them in the 6th "block"

Solution:
(Thx to Smathy!)

```
[[0, 0], 900.0]
[[3, 0], 1507.0]
[[0, 1], 3769.0]
[[3, 1], 6310.0]
[[0, 2], 0.0]
[[3, 2], 136.0]
[[0, 3], 100.0]
[[3, 3], 101.0] 

[[1, 0], 258.0]
[[1, 1], 1080.0]
[[1, 2], 64.0]
[[1, 3], 0.0] 

[[2, 0], 349.0]
[[2, 1], 1461.0]
[[2, 2], 72.0]
[[2, 3], 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you literally what you're asking for:

```
- @nutritions = Hash.new
- end_of_list = @ingredients.length
- @ingredients.each_with_index do |ingredient,i|
  - ingredient.nutritions.each_with_index do |nutrition, j|
    - @nutritions[[i,j]] = nutrition.amount
    - @nutritions[[end_of_list,j]] ||= 0
    - @nutritions[[end_of_list,j]] += nutrition.amount
```

There's probably a much nicer way to accomplish your real goal, but without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish it's impossible to guess the best way.